# "Create an Account" link missing from Google OAuth2 login page

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm implementing an iOS app which uses Youtube Data API v3. In order to get the OAuth access token, I'm opening Google OAuth 2.0 Auth page as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

The Google Account login form I'm seeing contains fields for Email and Password, but not the "Create An Account" link for those users who don't yet have a Google/Youtube account. I need to support the scenario where users may not have Google/Youtube accounts, and I would like to offer them chance to create the Google/Youtube account as part of the authentication flow.

Is there some option which can be used to enable the "Create an Account" link?

Answer (score 0):

Found this from [GTM OAuth 2 Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gtm-oauth2/S72u2biABTQ):

> Unfortunately, there's not currently an option for controlling
>   appearance of a sign-up link in the sign-in interface for Google
>   accounts.